# Is it possible to merge these two dataframes without a UID in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. These are examples of my dataframes:

```
#dataframe 1
Department <- c("ABS", "ABS", "ABS", "POL", "DOT")
Division <- c("BDO", "BL", "BL", "FSB", "DMS")
Gender <- c("M", "M", "M", "F", "M")
Grade <- c("15", "12","12", "16", "M2")
Salary20 <- c("47", "43", "41", "71", "16")
Overtime20 <- c("17", "43", "63", "0", "0")

df1 <- data.frame(Department, Division, Gender, Grade, Salary20, Overtime20)
df1
```

```
#dataframe 2
Department <- c("ABS", "ABS", "ABS", "POL", "HHS")
Division <- c("BDO", "BL", "BL", "FSB", "BHC")
Gender <- c("M", "M", "M", "F","F")
Grade <- c("15", "12","12", "16", "24")
Salary21 <- c("49", "45", "43", "72", "100")
Overtime21 <- c("35", "11", "10", "0", "40")

df2 <- data.frame(Department, Division, Gender, Grade, Salary21, Overtime21)
df2
```

I'll like to merge or left join `df2$Salary21` & `df2$Overtime21` to `df1` based on `Divison + Gender + Grade` just like the dataframe below:

```
#Final dataframe
Department <- c("ABS", "ABS", "ABS", "POL", "DOT", "HHS")
Division <- c("BDO", "BL", "BL", "FSB", "DMS", "BHC")
Gender <- c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F")
Grade <- c("15", "12","12", "16", "M2", "24")
Salary20 <- c("47", "43", "41", "71", "16", "0")
Overtime20 <- c("17", "43", "63", "0", "0", "0")
Salary21 <- c("49", "45", "43", "72", "0", "100")
Overtime21 <- c("35", "11", "10", "0", "0", "40")
df <- data.frame(Department, Division, Gender, Grade, Salary20, Overtime20, Salary21, Overtime21)
df
```

The problem is that there is no unique identifier (UID) and some rows are identical in `Divison + Gender + Grade` (example: ABS rows).

If this possible to merge? If so how?

Comment: If the is no unique identifier, how is one suppose to handle the duplicates?

Comment: @Dave2e  each row is supposed to represent a distinct person.

Comment: Back to my question, if lines 2 & 3 have the same Divison + Gender + Grade, but are different individuals. How do you know they are in the same order in both dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any way to accurately combine these dataframes without a unique identifier - as you mentioned, the identical rows mean that Division, Gender, and Grade are not enough.

I would try to add my own UID. The ease of this depends on how the data is formatted of course. I've included an example below to show how this then makes using merge or join easy.

```
#dataframe 1
Department <- c("ABS_1", "ABS_2", "ABS_3", "POL_1", "DOT_1")
Division <- c("BDO", "BL", "BL", "FSB", "DMS")
Gender <- c("M", "M", "M", "F", "M")
Grade <- c("15", "12","12", "16", "M2")
Salary20 <- c("47", "43", "41", "71", "16")
Overtime20 <- c("17", "43", "63", "0", "0")

df1 <- data.frame(Department, Division, Gender, Grade, Salary20, Overtime20)
df1

#dataframe 2
Department <- c("ABS_1", "ABS_2", "ABS_3", "POL_1", "HHS_1")
Division <- c("BDO", "BL", "BL", "FSB", "BHC")
Gender <- c("M", "M", "M", "F","F")
Grade <- c("15", "12","12", "16", "24")
Salary21 <- c("49", "45", "43", "72", "100")
Overtime21 <- c("35", "11", "10", "0", "40")

df2 <- data.frame(Department, Division, Gender, Grade, Salary21, Overtime21)
df2

# combine
df <- merge(df1,df2, by = c("Department","Division","Gender","Grade"), all = TRUE)
```

Comment: I believe this can work.  Since this is a set dataframe, how do you change the `Department` values ABS to ABS_1 ... ABS_n...?

Comment: What do you mean by set dataframe? Ideally you would have a way to create and apply an UID before the information is organized as is in the example you have provided. Like Dave2e noted above, when the data is in these two dataframes, you have no way of knowing which salary21 and overtime21 to pair with the ABS-BL-M-12 entries. I only knew how to pair it because you provided an example of what the output should look like. Is the order of entries in the dataframe relevant?